# What option should I be specifying in file-loader for the dev server to load the file correctly

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-file-loader

When I run my "webpack -p" my dist folder gets created and the image loaded with file-loader loads into the page correctly. When I run webpack-dev-server the image is the only thing that doesn't load correctly. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "sass-loader" }
        ],
      },
      {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: ['html-loader']
      },
      {
          test: /\.(pdf|jpg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
          use: [
              { 
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: '/img/', //Just to place it in a folder
                    publicPath: '/img/'
                }
            }
          ]
      }
    ]
  },
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
  }
};
```

My folder structure looks like this: (No idea how to make a more visual structure)

```
|-node_modules
|-src
   |- components
   |- img
       |- image.png
   |- styles
   index.html
   index.tsx
package.json
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.json
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I am still new to web-pack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file-loader`'s `outputPath` should be relative:

```
{ 
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[name].[ext]',
    outputPath: 'img/', // file pack output path, is relative path for `dist`
    publicPath: '/img/', // css file will use, is absolute path for server
}
```

Comment: It is always one character that sets apart a working config file from a not working one.